# Two conics with perpendicular directrices intersect at $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. Show that these points are concyclic.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Two conic sections are given, whose directrices are perpendicular to each other. It is known that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are intersections of the conics. Prove that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ lie on a common circle.

I don't know whether it's well-known. I have been trying some ways but most of them is helpless. I am thinking of using coordinates but I don't know how to write the equation of conics when we got the directrix.

What should I do now?

Comment: You can get the equation for a conic with eccentricity $e\neq 0$ from its focus and directrix via
$$(\text{distance from $(x,y)$ to focus})^2= e^2 \cdot (\text{distance from $(x,y)$ to directrix})^2$$ Do you know how to calculate the distance between two points, and the distance between a point and a line? The latter is quite easy if you choose convenient directrices. (The more you can say about what you *do* and *don't* know about the problem will help people know the best ways to assist you. Since comments are easily overlooked, add such information to the question itself.)

Comment: Come to think of it, a coordinate approach might not be best, as you'll have to deal with a quartic equation.

Comment: I see that the coodinate isn't nice, too. I will try some different ways and tell more.

Comment: Can you provide more context for this problem? For instance, if it's a textbook exercise, what topics were covered in that chapter (or in recent chapters)? If it's a contest problem or online challenge, is there any indication of what results might be useful? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I will consider the case of two ellipses $E_1$, $E_2$, the first with a horizontal major axis, the second with a vertical major axis of equation
$$E_i :P_i(x,y)= \frac{x^2}{a_i^2} + \frac{y^2}{b_i^2} + L_i(x,y) = 0$$
$i=1,2$, where $L_i$ are linear forms and $a_1>b_1$, $a_2 < b_2$.

The common points satisfy any linear combination
$$P(x,y) = \lambda P_1(x,y) + (1-\lambda) P_2(x,y)=0$$

We can choose $\lambda\in (0,1)$ so that the coefficients of $x^2$, $y^2$ are equal. That will be the equation of a circle.